# Как получить номер недели из даты типа '2016-08-17'?

Tags: python

Есть набор данных с датой https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xcM2KNkLQ5P9dd8INU6OuOKfvY1gKeQp
Нужно создать новый столбец с номером недели в году.
Как сделть столбец с номером времени года(1 2 3 4)?
Как это сделать?

Comment: У вас целых три вопроса в одном, определитесь с конкретным вопросом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df['Период'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Период'])
df['week'] = df['Период'].dt.week
df['season'] = (df['Период'].dt.month%12 + 3)//3
```

Получим:

```
    Период  КоличествоОборот    СуммаОборот week    season
0   2016-08-17  3   134,22  33  3
1   2016-08-18  1   44,2    33  3
2   2016-08-20  4   131,6   33  3
3   2016-08-22  1   45,5    34  3
4   2016-08-23  2   88,4    34  3
5   2016-08-24  1   45,5    34  3
6   2016-08-26  1   45,5    34  3
7   2016-08-29  1   43,2    35  3
8   2016-08-30  3   136,5   35  3
9   2016-08-31  1   47,5    35  3
10  2016-01-09  2   86,4    1   1
 . . .
```

и т. д.